# Bash copy files from multiple directories to multiple corresponding backup directories

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have multiple directories {`dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4`} on a Linux box.

There are multiple files in each directory (with the same extension lets say .zip) that I want to backup to corresponding directories {`dir1-bck,dir2-bck,dir3-bck,dir4-bck`}. 
I don't need to backup the whole folder just a few files in each.

How would I go about having the files copied from `dir1/*.zip` dropped in `dir1-bck` . . . for a list of directories provided. I am currently using:

```
cp -r src/dir1/*.zip dest/dir1-bck/
cp -r src/dir2/*.zip dest/dir2-bck/
cp -r src/dir3/*.zip dest/dir3-bck/
cp -r src/dir4/*.zip dest/dir4-bck/
```

Which works but has huge room for improvement.

Looking over the `xargs` man page and similar posts on the forum I feel it's the tool for this job but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a `for` loop will be just right. The exact form depends on how these directories are named. It can be:

```
cd src || exit 1
for d in "dir"{1..4}; do
   cp -r "$d"/*.zip "../dest/$d-bck/"
done
```

Notes:

- It's good to work from within `src` (`cd src`), so the variable contains a string that can be used in the target path without extra processing. The target path was adjusted by prepending `../` in this case, but in general it may be like `"/full/path/to/dest/$d-bck/"`.
- I quoted `dir` in case you substitute a name with spaces or so. I double-quoted `$d` for the same reason and [more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).
- If `*.zip` are files then you don't need `-r`.

Alternatively the `for` line might be:

```
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4; do
```

which would be useful if you need to specify few arbitrarily named directories. Or even:

```
for d in *; do
```

Few improvements can be made, like this:

```
( cd src || exit 1
for d in *; do
   dst="../dest/$d-bck/"
   [ -d "$d" ] && mkdir -p "$dst" && cp -- "$d"/*.zip "$dst"
done )
```

The improvements:

- All the code is run in a subshell (`(…)`) so `cd` won't affect the current shell even if you paste the code in a terminal. If it had to be a standalone script (executed, not sourced), then the subshell would be irrelevant.
- We check if `$d` is a directory.
- We attempt to create the destination directory (in case it doesn't exist).
- We will proceed with `cp` only if the destination directory exists.
- We use [double-dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) in case `$d` starts with a dash.

Possible problems:

- `"$d"/*.zip` may expand to too many items (`Argument list too long`). Your original commands are "flawed" in the same way. If there are "just a few files in each" directory then this should not be a problem.
- `"$d"/*.zip` may not expand (`*` will stay literal). It should do no harm, still the destination directory will be created beforehand. Additional logic may be desired to suppress directory creation in such case.
- The exit status of the whole snippet depends only on the last `[ … && mkdir … && cp …`. You need additional logic to make earlier problems affect the exit status.

Comment: +1 worked like a charm!